# Using PEAR libraries in custom Magento modules produces "Failed opening required..." error

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, pear, autoloader

I have written a Magento module to listen for the "OrderSave" event and perform some API calls to a third party application.  Most of the functionality is working great, but I needed to handle an XML response from the API and when I tried to use the PEAR XML_Unserializer class I received the following error:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'XML/Parser.php' (include_path='/Users/jeremymoore/Sites/Helm/html/app/code/local:/Users/jeremymoore/Sites/Helm/html/app/code/community:/Users/jeremymoore/Sites/Helm/html/app/code/core:/Users/jeremymoore/Sites/Helm/html/lib:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php:/usr/loca/zend//share/ZendFramework/library') in /Users/jeremymoore/Sites/Helm/html/lib/PEAR/XML/Unserializer.php on line 58

My module has an Observer.php file in the model which looks starts as follows:

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/PEAR/XML/Serializer.php';
require_once 'lib/PEAR/XML/Unserializer.php';
require_once 'lib/Pest/PestXML.php';
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();

class Helm_Litmos_Model_Observer
{
    public function hookToOrderSaveEvent()
    {
        //Do API Stuff Here
    }
}
```

The hookToOrderSaveEvent functon creates new instances of the serializer and unserializer classes.  Before I added the Unserializer code, I had everything working serializing objects and making API calls.  It seems that things break down when the XML_Unserializer class tries to reference Parser.php.

I'm not sure that the "require_once" method I'm using here is the appropriate way for me to include these libraries.  I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1 which is currently being used on my local machine running MAMP.

Any suggestions on a better way to autoload or include these libraries for use in my module or just ideas on how to fix what I have would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use `Mage::getBaseDir('lib')`

`require_once Mage::getBaseDir('lib').'/PEAR/XML/Serializer.php';`

Alan has a good article on Magento's base directories:

http://alanstorm.com/magento_base_directories

Comment: I'll give that a try. Am I correct in assuming that the AutoLoader should take care of these, or am I mistaking that for something else?

Comment: From my understanding lib/ would not be auto loaded. More details: http://alanstorm.com/magento_class_abstration_autoload